# General ffmpeg command for encoding all formats to FLV

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am creating a video sharing/tube site and I'm in need of a single good general purpose ffmpeg command to use to transcode any video that's uploaded by my users.

I'm surprised more people haven't published good examples of a good **general** ffmpeg command for converting to flv format. By general, I mean being able to specify an input file in any format (wmv, avi, webm, etc.) and produce an FLV file that has great quality.

I am looking for a **single** ffmpeg command that can:

- Produce great looking video for the web (no artifacts, maintain original quality etc.)
- But also reduce file size to make it web friendly

I realize these are competing requirements and I would consider video quality to be the priority when it comes to a tradeoff but at the same time, I know you can have great quality and still reduce the file size of the original file dramatically.

I would have used MP4 with H264 but the patent stuff scares me and I don't want to pay for that so I'm stuck with FLV.

Answer (score 2):

```
ffmpeg -i in.avi -c:v libx264 -vprofile main -vf scale=-1:480 -c:a libvo_aacenc -ac 2 -ar 44100 out.flv
```

This should result in

FLV container

H.264 video

Main Profile

480p

AAC audio

2 channels (stereo)

44100 Hz audio sample rate

128 kbit/s audio bitrate (FFmpeg default)

http://svnpenn.blogspot.com/search/label/FFmpeg